# How to disable a specific warning in g++

Tags: g++, compiler-warnings

First of all I don't know why "g++ -std=c++0x -Wall" would give me *warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and string macro [-Wliteral-suffix]*  on the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

#define BEGIN   "<b>"
#define END "</b>"

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wliteral-suffix"
int main()
{
  std::cout << "hello " BEGIN"world"END "\n";
}
```

Second, I followed [gcc doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) to ignore "-Wliteral-suffix" but still got the warning. How do I suppress the warning?  And why does the compiler warn in the first place?

Comment: You don't know what the warning is for, but you want to suppress it anyway? If you don't know what it's for, how can you determine that suppressing it is the appropriate response?

Comment: This warning looks like a gcc bug, and that's why I want to suppress it.

Comment: Apparently the failure to suppress is a known gcc bug (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61653). I have no idea why it cares about this - the code looks fine to me (although the #defines are an eye sore). You could fix it by simply sticking a space between the literal and the #define string - it won't change the text.

Comment: @zhao The warning is not even remotely a GCC bug. The fact that suppressing doesn't work is a bug, but you should just fix your code to make it valid.

Comment: @hvd I'm unfamiliar with that requirement, and while no doubt gcc is right, I find myself wondering why it is necessary - especially since it wasn't there in the earlier standards. Also - could you perhaps try commenting without resorting to insults?

Comment: @H.Guijt I included a link to a page on user-defined literals already. Is it not clear what ambiguity they would introduce if all existing code had to be kept valid?

Comment: @hvd User-defined literals do not come into it. In this scenario the pre-processor will already replace BEGIN and END by their literal string values before we ever get to the stage where user-defined literals are being evaluated. The string will therefore expand to `"hello " "<b>""world""</b>" "\n"`. Note that none of the literals could be interpreted as a user-defined literal; the only rule that applies is string concatenation of adjacent strings. I still don't see the problem.

Comment: @H.Guijt In standard C++11, user-defined literals make `"world"END` a single token. When `END` does not appear as an identifier, it is not subject to macro replacement. That's by design, since otherwise (recognising UDLs by adjacent string literal and identifier tokens) any amount of whitespace would be allowed between them. And it's by design that `""s` means the same thing regardless of whether `s` is defined as a macro. (But not of this should have been in the comments here. It could be an interesting related question, but it shouldn't be a comment on this one.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have summarized it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, to summarize: the failure to suppress the warning is a known gcc bug (gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61653). Since you cannot (and really, should not) suppress the warning, the easiest fix is to put a space between the literal and the #define string. You can safely do this; it won't change the output text.

The reason this is no longer allowed is because characters directly after a literal string are treated as user-defined literals, which is a new feature in C++11. User-defined literals are considered to be part of the same single token as the literal they modify, thus `END` will not be subject to replacement by the earlier #define.

Comment: I never heard of 'user defined literal' before, and also wonder I would ever use this feature.  Apparently gcc knows that I'm using a string immediately followed by a macro (as the warning message reads), so why does it still warn given that there is no ambiguity and it could just expand the macro?

Comment: Because there might be ambiguity in other cases, I suppose. As for the feature being useful - I can certainly think of possible uses, but I have some reservations about possible namespace pollution if everybody were to use it as much as they could. We'll have to see how that develops, I guess...